# Control where element appears in jquery .wrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am building some 2 jQuery functions to wrap a gravityform inputs with some bootstrap prepend and append input-group html.

I trying to control the position of the input html which I am wrapping with the new html.

For example, I am trying to wrap an `INPUT` like this...

**Prepend input group wrap example...**

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">'content'</span>
  </div>
```

---

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
```

---

```
</div>
```

**Append input group wrap example...**

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
```

---

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
```

---

```
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">'content'</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

See complete fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/9xg5bkrp/2/

This is the mark up for the bootstrap documentation...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

This is my wrap jquery functions below, but when I use `.wrap()` I cannot control where the `INPUT` is positioned in the html.

```
// field 1
gformInputPrepend('#field_1','https://');
gformInputAppend('#field_1','domain.com');

// field 2
gformInputAppend('#field_2','%');


// gform prepend input group function
gformInputPrepend = function(elem, content) {

  // find element human
  $input = $(elem).find('INPUT');

  // check if .input-group does not exist
  if (!$(elem + ' .input-group').length > 0) {

    // wrap the input with the complete prepend.input-group
    $input.wrap('<div class="input-group">\n' +
      '<div class="input-group-prepend">\n' +
      '<span class="input-group-text">' + content + '</span>\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '</div>');

  } else {

    // this is working fine

    // just prepend the .input-group-prepend div
    $(elem).find('.input-group').prepend('<div class="input-group-prepend">\n' +
      '<span class="input-group-text">' + content + '</span>\n' +
      '</div>\n')

  }

}


// gform append input group
gformInputAppend = function(elem, content) {

  // find element human
  $input = $(elem).find('INPUT');

  // check if .input-group does not exist
  if (!$(elem + ' .input-group').length > 0) {

     // wrap the input with the complete append .input-group
    $input.wrap('<div class="input-group">\n' +
      '<div class="input-group-append">\n' +
      '<span class="input-group-text">' + content + '</span>\n' +
      '</div>\n' +
      '</div>');

  } else {

    // this is working fine

    // just append the .input-group-append div
    $(elem).find('.input-group').append('<div class="input-group-append">\n' +
      '<span class="input-group-text">' + content + '</span>\n' +
      '</div>\n')

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `before()` and `after()` along with `wrap()`

```
$input
   // wrap input 
   .wrap('<div class="input-group"></div>')

   // before input
   .before('<div class="input-group-prepend"> ... </div>')

   // or after input
   .after('<div class="input-group-append"> ... </div>')
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/1y20n57s/10/)

[**Shortened code**](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/4fr9ygw8/6/)

Comment: Thank you so much dude, so simple. Nice one!